# Simple cin cout Code runs by "build and run" but dosent work from bin/debug/x.exe

Tags: c++

I'm new to coding. I just made this simple code by using codeblocks. It works perfectly from the "build and run" option but when running the ".exe" file, it closes instead of working when a value is entered.

I have reinstalled codeblocks two times, but still it isn't working.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
  int no;
  cout << "Type the number u need the square of" << endl;
  cin >> no;
  cout << " The square of " << no << " is " << no*no << endl;

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: As soon as the program finishes, the console exits, and you don't have time to see the output. Try opening a console (command.exe) and then running your program from there. That way, the console window will stay open and you will have time to see the output.

Comment: ty. will try right now.

Comment: and how do i transport the code? i mean running it on my friends pc just like a normal program?

Answer (score 1):

You can make the application wait till your input before it closes. Add two lines at the end of your code:

```
std::cout << "Press enter to quit.\n";
std::cin.ignore();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you run it directly by clicking on the .exe, then the program will close as soon as it’s finished. This closes the terminal window too.

If you run the program directly from the terminal, this won’t happen (so start it up *inside the terminal*, instead of clicking on the .exe).

Alternatively you can have it wait for user input after printing the value but before exiting. This will give you a chance to see what the value is.